# Kafka cannot see topic information when launching kafka-consumer-groups.sh tools script

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using Kafka 0.9 and I would like to use utility scripts provided into the *bin* folder of Kafka installation to check some information about my group, like partitions, lags, etc.

I have clients belonging to the group "my-group" which are correctly producing/consuming to/from 2 topics:
"topic-1" and "topic-2".

Simplifying, consumer code is the following, really basic, with properties having more or less default values.

```
public void run() {
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(getConsumerProperties());
    consumer.subscribe(topics);
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, Message> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        ...
    }
}

private Properties getConsumerProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,         bootstrapServer);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,                 clientId);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,                  groupId);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,        autoCommit);            
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,   autoCommitInterval.intValue()); 
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,         autoOffsetReset);       
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,        requestTimeout.intValue());     
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,        sessionTimeout.intValue());     
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,     heartbeatInterval.intValue());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,    keyDeserializer);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueDeserializer);
        return properties;
}
```

If I run the following script

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:1881 --new-consumer --describe --group my-group
```

I get partitions information only about "topic-1", but no data about the other topic.

Anyone of you already tried to use this script and experienced this behavio of partial result shown?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a few steps (e.g., creating topics, producing, consuming, ...) you take that lead to this issues? Are all consumers using the `--new-consumer` switch?

Comment: @vahid I edited my post to better explain  my problem. I don't have any issue related to producing and consuming messages.

Comment: Can you paste here the command and the config file you use to run the consumers? Thanks.

Comment: @vahid I edited again my post putting consumer code, though I don't think this would be useful to find the solution, especially if you have never run the kafka-consumer-groups.sh script.

Comment: remove the `--new-consumer` from the command